# Convert Boost Gregorian Date to POD

Tags: datetime, boost

Is there an easy way to convert a boost::gregorian::date to a Plain old data type? I need to be able to pass it through a C DLL interface. I'd rather not convert it to it's year/month/day components back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    boost::gregorian::date date1(2013, boost::date_time::Feb, 25);
    std::cout << date1 << std::endl;
    boost::gregorian::date::date_int_type pod = date1.day_number();
    std::cout << pod << std::endl;
    boost::gregorian::date date2(pod);
    std::cout << date2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for but didn't find, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You could pick some epoch date, and then get the `date_duration` between your "current" date and the epoch, then call `days()` on the duration to get a `long`. Pass the `long` through your C DLL, then on the other side create a new `date_duration` with the same number of days, add it to the epoch, and you should be back to your original date.

You should be able to easily wrap this in a couple of functions, e.g.

```
long days_since_epoch_from_date(date)
date date_from_days_since_epoch(long)
```